# Creation of web page to show numbers with intervals

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, visual-studio, customization

does anyone know how to make a **WEB PAGE** that shows numbers from, for example, 1 to 100 and that when it reaches 100 it resets to 1 again? and that **you can change the time between number and number**.

*Using **html**, **javascript** or anything that was needed.* Thx :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like that?

```js
let countArea = document.getElementById('count-area');
let speedInput = document.getElementById('speed');
let speed = Number(speedInput.value);

function setSpeed() {
  speed = Number(speedInput.value)
}

function count() {
  if (100 > Number(countArea.textContent)) {
    countArea.textContent = Number(countArea.textContent) + 1;
  } else {
    countArea.textContent = 0;
  };
  setTimeout(count, speed)
}
count()
speedInput.addEventListener('change', setSpeed)
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Number counter</title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="count-area">0</p>
  <input type="range" id="speed" min="50" max="1000">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yep, something similar, I'm new to everything that has to do with development, and I just want to make an API to check later on something else,

Only that I would need the speed to be put in the code in a "variable". and when checked it looks like this:

```
{
 "number": "0"
}
```

Comment: If you want to create an API, you should use server-side code ([help to start on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/First_steps/Introduction)), but the starting you should know a minimal client-side programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean.
If you mean just a script that writes numbers from 1 to 100 multiple times this can work:

```
<div id='somediv'></div>
<script>
var times = 4;

for (var n=1;n<times;n++){
    for (var i=1;i<101;i++){
    somediv.innerHTML+='<br>'+i

    }
}
</script>
```

To set delay between them can add timeout like here:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp
Depending in what way you want that delay, the rest will be different.

To change how many times it will write 1-100 change the value of 'times', currently it will write it 1 time less then the number(so 3 times), can change that as well.

Edit: Aha!Ok so this can do something similar:

```
<div id='somediv'></div>


<script>
setInterval(displayCounter, 1000);
var i=0;
function displayCounter() {
    
  document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML = i;
  i=i+1;
  if (i==100){i=1};
}
</script>
```

It will cycle from 0 to 100, then start from 0 again. Currently its 1 second apart(1000 miliseconds). You can make it more or less by changing the 1000 to something else(3000 will be 3 seconds).

Edit 2:

```
{<br>
"number":"<span id='somediv'></span>"<br>
}

<script>
setInterval(displayCounter, 100);
var i=0;
function displayCounter() {
    
  document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML = i;
  i=i+1;
  if (i==100){i=1};
}
</script>
```

If you want it to start from 1 change:
var i=0;
to
var i=1;

If you want it to be to more or less then 100 change:
if (i==100)...
to 50 for example would be:
if (i==50)...

And can't think of anything more. For style can use css on #somediv.

Edit 3:

```
{<br>
"number":"<span id='somediv'></span>"<br>
}

<script>
setInterval(displayCounter, 1000);

var i = new Date().getSeconds();


function displayCounter() {
    
  document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML = i;
  i=i+1;
  if (i==100){i=1};
}
</script>
```

This will start the counter(1-100) from the current seconds of the clock. I'm not sure it will be the same for everyone, though, browser may load slower in some places or other factors.

Edit 4:

```
{<br>
"number":"<span id='somediv'></span>"<br>
}

<script>
setInterval(displayCounter, 1000);

var i = new Date().getSeconds();
if (i>0){somediv.innerHTML = i-1 ;} else if (i==0){somediv.innerHTML = 100}

function displayCounter() {
    
  document.getElementById("somediv").innerHTML = i;
  i=i+1;
  if (i==100){i=1};
}
</script>
```

Comment: thx man, something similar, but that updates automatically, I know it's going to sound silly but for example the youtube time bar, which advances one by one, and when it reaches 59 it goes to 00 (seconds)

Comment: Edited it with counter and 1 second apart. : )

Comment: wow! It's great, how can I make it look like this? ex: https://i.imgur.com/ZFyVhn1.png

Comment: Thanks!Added one more edit to fit the image.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that if several people connect, they are synchronized? I know it's very specific

Comment: If you can synhronize it with the server time in some way.
But that may need another language and scripts on the server. Node Js maybe, if we want it to stay javascript or something. It would really depend on what the server is running on.

Only from the client/browser we can't get that information(how many people are connected to it, or what is the server time). We can only get the time on the client machines I think.

Comment: It doesn't matter if I need more complexity, I could host "the api" in replit or similar

Comment: If it's possible to somehow get them to read the time or something, that would be best.

Comment: Will edit above : )

Comment: bro, you are too good, know how I can remove the delay that exists when entering the html? the number does not appear for about 0.6s or so

Comment: I was wondering the same.Will edit with fixes . : )

Comment: The code works perfectly, it gives me this error on Discord https://i.imgur.com/oLc4U9e.png ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ I don't know why it will be, I'll pass you a page of an API that if it reads it correctly, maybe there you can see something that can make it "readable" https://api.popcatdev.repl.co/instagram?user=test

Comment: Ohh... This needs JSON...
We have JSON as output, but you are sending it the whole code it seems. It can't run it to get to the output.

Simple way to say it, it seems it needs you to send it:

"number": "20"

While you are sending it the whole code and it just can't execute it.
I have no idea how to send it only the output, however, currently the browser is receiving the output. 
If it accepts URLs we can probably make it connect to an URL. 
But even then you will need someone with browser and open the page to get the request.

Comment: Is there no way to make this information happen to be in a .json?